# What Scala feature implements factory patterns and persistent (singleton?) objects?

Tags: scala

What Scala feature can help a class become a factory? And return persistent objects like database connections?

---

I am most familiar with Python, less familiar with Java and spent only a few hours with Scala (tutorials). I am working the counter-intuitive ideas about Scala classes into my head; so I am thinking in terms of **more** intuitive features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See companion object in scala:

```
class Example(val string:String) {
  private var extraData = ""
  override def toString = string+extraData
}
object Example {
  def apply(base:String, extras:String) = {
    val s = new Example(base)
    s.extraData = extras
    s
  }
  def apply(base:String) = new Example(base)
}
println(Example("hello"," world"))
println(Example("hello"))
```

There are connected with class with the same name.

For persistence objects scala use the same stuff as java - [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) [openlink](/questions/tagged/openlink)

See [Using JPA With Scala](http://www.hars.de/2009/03/jpa-with-scala.html)

Comment: If the factory method is called `apply`, then you can create new objects using just the class name with no extra method written out.